# The page reloads when I add my codes to functions.php in sage (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

The page reloads when I use get_transient function.

[image]

The below statement shows my codes:

I'm using sage and below codes placed in a blade file like feature.blade.php

```
<div class="popular-products-holder">

<?php
    $products = get_remote_product('home');
    
    if( ! empty( $products['data'] ) ) :
    
    foreach( $products['data'] as $product) :
    if($product->images[0]->src) :
?>
        <div id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" style="background-image:url();" data-srcset="<?php echo $product->images[0]->src; ?>" class="lazy-bg col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 pp">
          <div class="title-select row align-items-end">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 align-self-center product-info">
              <h4>{{ $product->name }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 align-self-center">
              <a id="select{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-black btn-block product-sel" href="/find-what-you-need-where-ever-you-are/#filter-block-start">Select</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<?php
    endif; endforeach; endif;
?>
</div>
```

I used the below codes in function php:

```
function get_remote_product($page = null){

    // source url
    $remote_url = 'https://woocommerce-490897.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products';    
    
    // check the transient
    $body = get_transient('prospray_product_'.$page);
    
    // fetch data from source if not exist transient
    if(empty($body)){
        $data = config_get_remote($page,$remote_url);
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $data['result'] );
        set_transient('prospray_product_'.$page,$body,86400);
    }
    
    return ['data' => json_decode($body) , 'reference_site'=>$remote_url];
}

function config_get_remote($page = null, $remote_url){
    
    // per page
    $count = 12;

    // per page for home    
    if($page == 'home'){
        $count=4;
        $page=1;
    }

    // check language    
    $lang = weglot_get_current_language() == 'no' ? 'nb' : 'en';
    
    // set paginiation
    $page = $page != null ? "&page={$page}" : '' ;
    
    
    // make query
    $params = "?per_page={$count}&orderby=menu_order&order=asc&lang={$lang}".$page;
    
    
    // set headers
    $auth  =  array(
                'headers' => array(
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'ck_a442a87286a6f9269e54dd47cbf:cs_8b3a4ff671e46843a88415e4214' )
                )        
            );
    
    // get data
    $result = wp_remote_get( $remote_url.$params ,$auth);
        
    if( is_wp_error( $result ) ) :
        return  FALSE;
    endif;
    
    // get total pages for next/prev links
    $totalpages  = wp_remote_retrieve_header($result,'x-wp-totalpages');
    
    return [
        'result'=>$result,
        'totalpages'=>$totalpages
    ];
    
}
```

How can I fix it? ( I see the reload page in waterfall whenever I use the transient )
I checked the plugins and without any plugins I had same result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `style="background-image:url();"` from html and it fixed!